# Proper Asynchronous Request Handling - JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, web

I am making an application. The application makes two requests, the first is to the MapBox API to load a map and the second is to the Yelp Fusion API (through my node server). The through throttling testing I have found that the MapBox Call takes aproximately 1/2 the time to complete as the Yelp Call.

I am a bit confused how to manage the two requests. Do I load one and then the next? Do I load them both and then create two input functions to account for the Yelp loading first/ the MapBox loading first?

Here is how my code is structured currently:

```
      // -------------------------- // Yelp API Call // ------------------------- //
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      "food_type": getParameterByName('type', window.location.href),
      "geolocation": false,
      "long": -1,
      "lat": -1,
      "radius": 1000,
      "limit": 30
    },
    success: function(response) {
      YelpCallback(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log("Failure");
      console.log(xhr)
    },
    url: POST_baseurl + "yelp"
  });


  // -------------------------- // MapBox API Call // ------------------------- //
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.<accesstoken>.<accesstoken>';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/jeremysmorgan/<mapstyle url>',
    center: [lat, long],
    zoom: 13
  });
  map.on('load', function(e) {
    var map_load_time = new Date().getTime() - map_start_time;
    console.log("map_load_time: " + map_load_time);

    MapCallback(e);
  });

    function YelpCallback(data) {
  yelp_loaded = true;
  yelp_data = data;
  if (map_loaded) {
    main();
  }
}

function MapCallback(e) {
  map_loaded = true;
  if (YelpCallback) {
    main();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe some code? Do you load Yelp Fusion in NodeJS? If so, why don't you load the map then run an AJAX call for Yelp? If they're both in the front-end, contain the Yelp call inside `MapBox.onload`.

Comment: I love your Arduino projects, by the way. Something I should work on too, but robotics resources in my country are scarce.

Comment: Hi @Vic, The code is included, and thanks! glad you like my work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. Read up on callbacks (proper ones), they're very helpful. http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/

```
function YelpAjax(callback)
{
  $.ajax({
    //yelp request,
    success: function(response){
      callback(response); //once done, call this argument with parameter: response
    }
  });
}

map.onload('load', function(e){
  //same stuff

  YelpAjax(function(response){ //this anonymous function is the argument.
    main();
  })
})
```

Contain your Yelp AJAX request in a function with a callback. Put this function in `map.onload`. Call `main()` afterwards.

It's effectively like putting `main()` inside your Ajax success, but with less literal nesting.

```
$.ajax({
  //yelp request,
  success: function(response){
    main();
  }
});
```

You could also try the async library which allows you to control asynchronous functions very elegantly, but you might need to brush up first before tackling something like that. http://caolan.github.io/async/